# Проверка на nullptr указателя на функцию

Tags: c++, arduino

Пытаюсь сделать проверку указателя на nullptr. Но она почему-то проходит, не срабатывает условие и контроллер уходит в перезагрузку, видимо, крашится.

Главный код:

```
VirtualEnv* env = new VirtualEnv();

void test_interrupt_call_null(){
    // функция должна вернуть false, т.к вызов не прошел из-за того, что указатель на функцию не определен
    bool result = env->callInterruptByPin(131);
    TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(result);
}
```

VirtualEnv.h:

```
typedef void (*InterruptFunction)();

class VirtualEnv: public IEnvironment
{
    public:
        virtual void setInterrupt(int pin, void(*callback)(), int mode);

        bool callInterruptByPin(int pin);
    private:
        int pins_state[54]; 
        InterruptFunction interruptCallbacks[24];
};
```

VirtualEnv.cpp:

```
void VirtualEnv::setInterrupt(int pin, void(*callback)(), int mode) 
{
    this->interruptCallbacks[pin] = callback;
}



bool VirtualEnv::callInterruptByPin(int pin) 
{
    InterruptFunction callback = this->interruptCallbacks[pin];

    // вот тут, видимо, callback nullptr проходит, вызывается callback() на nullptr и контроллер перезагружается
    if (callback != nullptr && *callback != nullptr && callback != NULL && *callback != NULL){
        callback();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: У где у вас массив нулями забивается? Теоретически, должен в конструкторе, но что-то  я текста конструктора не вижу

Comment: @gbg, нигде. То есть, вы предлагаете в конструкторе класса проходится for'ом и закидывать туда nullptr'ы? Я тоже об этом думал, но может есть какие-то другие подходы? Более... Оптимизированные, что ль)

Comment: Какую "оптимизацию" вы ожидаете?

Comment: В функции `callInterruptByPin` напишите просто `if (callback) callback();`. Естественно, при создании объекта обнулите массивы.

Comment: ¿Если он нигде не забивается нулями, то как по-вашему будет работать проверка на nullptr?

Comment: Хм, странно, но проблема не решилась даже после добавления заполнения массива nullptr'ами в конструкторе класса...

Comment: `if (callback != nullptr && *callback != nullptr && callback != NULL && *callback != NULL)` параноя... это просто `if(callback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

прошу прощения , но

```
 bool result = env->callInterruptByPin(131);
```

обращается к 132му элементу массива , тогда как их 24. Какое значение там в памяти, одному Ктулху известно.

По поводу инициализации. Первой строчки `VirtualEnv* env = new VirtualEnv();` достаточно только если у класса и его родителя нет конструкторов.  Если же у родителя конструктор есть, следует   продекларировать свой:

```
 VirtualEnv() : IEnvironment{}, pins_state{}, interruptCallbacks{} {}
```

Если компилятор не поддерживает С++11, такое не пройдет. Но можно определить свой тип указазателя , который себя инициализирует или использовать `std::function`